# generate json from objects in an array

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have following method

```
def build_json
  range = @model.OBJECT.item_ranges.object1.as_json
  ranges.map do |range|  
    {
       heading1: some_method(range["something"],
       body: range["something1"]  
    }
  end
end
```

There are two objects `["object1", "object2"]` in `@model.OBJECT.item_ranges.as_json.keys`

How can i loop over both the objects in same method build_json and create json?

Thanks

Comment: just put a `.to_json` after the second to last `end`?

Comment: that'd just create json for object1 right? i want to create it for both object1 and object2

Comment: You want to create a single JSON object ( an encoded array of hashes ) or two JSON objects (2 encoded hashes)?